# is it possible to show the AP and AR scalar metric from previous steps to the latest from eval.py?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am using `TensorFlow`'s object detection API. I have my trained custom model with 20000 steps and I want to check its Accuracy metric from the beginning of training to the latest checkpoint.

I have tried

`python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir=traininglite --eval_dir=eval --pipeline_config_path=traininglite/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco.config`

but it shows only a single accuracy during its latest checkpoint.

Comment: Use `model_main.py` to train your model and then use tensorboard to visualize the precision and recall metrics.

Comment: but i already used the legacy/train.py and it cost too much time to start training again. is there any solution? @danyfang